# how to use wagtail admin page edit interface by normal user

Tags: wagtail

I'm planning to create a website, and the pages contents will be created by both Admin and normal(logged in) users.

- Is wagtail admin page supposed to be only for the admin users to create page contents ?
- Is it a bad idea to give normal users the admin access with limited permissions to allow them to create their page contents?
- If it is a bad idea, is it still possible to use the awesome admin page editor interface for the normal user?

I'm wondering how other people handles the page creation by the normal users in wagtail..

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you're defining "admin user". By the most literal definition, as soon as you give a user access to the Wagtail admin, they're an admin user...

Wagtail *is* designed to support multiple user roles - through features like [the permission system](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/permissions.html) and the "submit for moderation" option, so that you can give people access to edit pages without giving them total control over the site. For example, the [Royal College of Art](https://www.rca.ac.uk/) - the site that Wagtail was originally built for - gives students limited-permission accounts on Wagtail so that they can create and submit pages about their work in the [RCA Now](https://www.rca.ac.uk/showcase/rcanow/) section, without giving them edit access to the rest of the site.

Comment: How is this accomplished? Where could I find some documentation, examples, etc? Is RCA available in a repo?

Comment: @EdHenderson It's documented at the "permission system" link above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give normal user to wagatil admin access than you have to give below permission as mentioned in photo.

[image: Here Wagtail Admin can give permission to route admin page]

You can see this in

> wagtail admin > settings > groups > other permissions > check "can access wagtail admin"

And might be clear that you have'nt given Admin Access Role.